# unable to access usb in debian 12 through Home folder

Tags: debian, ubuntu, usb, fdisk, home

when I plug the usb in and try this code :

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

I see my USB device in results but can't open it through HomeFolder,
I see nothing.

How to fix it in Debian 12 ? (thanks for help)

Comment: what does "open it through HomeFolder" mean? that seems to make no sense whatsoever to me!

Comment: Did you mount the disk?  Does the disk automount?  Was there a failure with disk automounting?  Without further information, I am not sure there is an answer to your question.